# Using a foreach loop to loop through a list of TextBoxes

Tags: c#, foreach

I figured this out using a for loop, but when I try with a foreach loop I get a cannot covert TextBox to int.  I haven't used a lot of foreach loops, what am I doing wrong?

This works

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    list[i].Text = "5.0";
}
```

How do I get this to work

```
foreach (TextBox element in list)
{
    list[element].Text = "5.0";   //get Error her
}
```

Comment: And to explain the downvotes: your question is extremely low effort, a simple google search for "c# foreach" would have given you the answer.

Comment: When you say `foreach (TextBox element in list)` you are actually getting every `TexBox` present in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
foreach (TextBox element in list)
{
    element.Text = "5.0";
}
```

In your first code sample `list[i]` represents a single item in the list a `TextBox`, in your `foreach` loop you have `element` for the same thing.

IMO, *Usually*, modification in `foreach` loop should be avoided, you might end up writing code,  where you are changing the actual list, *(not just a property of an object inside the list)*, and end up with an exception, "Collection was modified after enumeration".

Answer (score 2):

Use just `element`

```
foreach (TextBox element in list)
{
    element.Text = "5.0";
}
```